# What's the row picture of $Ax=$b if $A$ is a 3 by 3 matrix with 1 dependent column?

Tags: linear-algebra

Since the matrix has a dependent column, the column picture would be 3 vectors inside a plane in 3-dimensional space, and $Ax=b$ either has infinite solutions ($b$ inside the plane) or no solution ( $b$ outside the plane)
So, the row picture should be 3 planes meeting at a line or with no common intersection (the three planes don't intersect in a point)
Is this true about the row picture? How can I show it (without using the column picture).
Thanks in advance.

Comment: One of the three columns is a linear combination of the other two

Answer (score 1):

So you have $${\bf A}\boldsymbol{x}=\boldsymbol{b}$$ but with $$\boldsymbol{x}={\bf P}\boldsymbol{u}$$ where $\boldsymbol{u}$ a two-component vector (the unknown independent values) and ${\bf P}$ a 3×2 projection matrix that combines the two independent values of $u$ into the 3 dependent values of $x$.

The solution of this follows the weighted pseudo-inverse

$$ \begin{aligned}
 {\bf A}{\bf P}\boldsymbol{u} & =\boldsymbol{b} \\
 \left({\bf P}^{\intercal}{\bf A}{\bf P}\right)\boldsymbol{u} & = {\bf P}^{\intercal}\boldsymbol{b}\\
 \boldsymbol{u}& = \left({\bf P}^{\intercal}{\bf A}{\bf P}\right)^{-1}{\bf P}^{\intercal}\boldsymbol{b} \\
  \boldsymbol{x} & = {\bf P}\left({\bf P}^{\intercal}{\bf A}{\bf P}\right)^{-1}{\bf P}^{\intercal}\boldsymbol{b}
\end{aligned} $$